# How to check users' asynchronous status tasks from AWS comprehend

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-comprehend

Dears,
I am new to AWS and I am looking for function/code to check users' asynchronous status tasks from AWS comprehend.
I am checking boto3 docs - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/comprehend.html#client but not able to find my answer.
can you please guide me
thanks

Comment: class ComprehendDetect:
       def __init__(self, comprehend_client):
        self.comprehend_client = comprehend_client

    def detect_languages(self, job):
              
        
        try:
            response = self.comprehend_client.client.list_entities_detection_jobs(JobStatus=job)
            status = response['JobStatus']
            logger.info("Detected %s status.")
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Job in progress.")
            raise
        else:
            return status

Comment: does this work ? please advise

Answer (score 0):

To check the async job status for Amazon Comprehend, you can use describe job API. For instance, `describe_dominant_language_detection_job()`, the response will include the Job Status information:

```
'JobStatus': 'SUBMITTED'|'IN_PROGRESS'|'COMPLETED'|'FAILED'.
```

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/comprehend.html#Comprehend.Client.describe_dominant_language_detection_job